# nonlinear optimization problem,a) solve the problem geometrically.b) verify the optimality of the function by the Kuhn - Tucker conditions

Tags: optimization

Can you guide me on how to solve this exercise? I need your help please. I don't understand the correct way to do it. being a nonlinear programming problem. can it be solved by simplex method? or the simplex method only applies to linear optimization? Can you tell me the step by step of this exercise?

minimize
$ x^2_1- x_1 x_2+ 2x^2_2-4x_1 -5x_2 $

$x_1 + 2x_2≤6$

$ x_1≤2$

$x_1≥0 , x_2 ≥0$

a) solve the problem geometrically.

b) verify the optimality of the function by the Kuhn - Tucker conditions

Comment: I would sketch the constraints and draw the level sets of the cost (which are ellipses).

Comment: I don't usually recommend this sort of approach, but Desmos might help.

Comment: Do you know how to solve (a) the unconstrained minimization problem? (b) do you know whether the objective function is a convex function? If you have difficulties in answering any of these questions... you really need to study more basic stuff related optimization before solving a problem like this.

Comment: Hello, you can clarify this question, when it claims to interpret the problem geometrically what it refers to? Is it to graph the problem? I do not understand, if you can clarify this I will be very grateful